# ajax laravel post in foreach return blank page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

i just create like system with laravel project, Right now when I click the button a blank page is loaded on the second element of forearch(). I don't know why this is happening or how I can fix it, somebody can help me? thanks in advance and
this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
});

$('#frm-insert').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#submit-form').remove();
    $('#div2').show();

    var token = '{{Session::token()}}';
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var post = $(this).attr('method');
    var product_review_id = $("#product_review_id").val();
    var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
    var like = $("#like").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:post,
        url:url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { product_review_id, user_id, like,token: token},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        success:function (data) {
            //                            read_like();
            $("#ajax_results").html(data[0]);
        }
    })
});
```

`

Form action in foreach()

```
 <form action="{{route('like')}}" method="post" id="frm-insert" style="margin: 0">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product_review_id" value="{{$item->id}}" id="product_review_id">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="like" id="like" value="1">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="user_id"  id="user_id">
                                            <div class="like_comment_form">
                                                <div id="div2" style="display: none"><span style="color: #009900">thank you for your feedback</span></div>
                                                <button id="submit-form">Like</button>
                                                <span style=" color: #dddddd; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 5px">|</span>
                                                <div class="comment_link">
                                                    <a href="">Comment</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

My Controller

```
 public function add_like(Request $r){
    if ($r->ajax()){
        $user = Auth::user();

        $like = new Like();
        $like['product_review_id']=$r->product_review_id;
        $like['user_id']= $user->id;
        $like['like']=$r->like;
        $like->save();
            return response(['msg'=>'insert success']);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try again after removing $r->ajax() from controller and print some static word for debugging